# Pi3 has 7 pullup resistors, I need 8

Tags: pi-3

I'm making a customer controller for the Pi3. This controller is very basic and requires 8 push buttons. My problem is I have 7 pullup resistors on the Pi3 and I have 8 buttons. There are plenty of pulldown resistors.

My questions are:

- Can I easily convert a pull down to a pull up?
- Will pull down resistors prevent floating input?

I'm a software engineering student.

Comment: Are you writing a driver for the Pi? That's obviously where the runner hits the road with this question...

Comment: What do you mean by "I have 7 pullup resistors"? To the best of my knowledge, all of the GPIOs on the BCM2835 can be configured to pull either up or down.

Answer (score 1):

Pull up or pull down resistors on a button merely set the default state of the input. You wire the button slightly differently in either case.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyzpTA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The capacitor is optional, and just adds a bit of hardware "debounce" to your button, just to ease the software burden slightly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a pull-up resistor between the input pin and the positive supply - you don't need to depend on any internal pull-ups (or pull-downs) in the Pi.

If you wish t use the internal pull-down resistors, you will need to connect your switches between the input pin and the positive supply.  The software logic will also need to be changed, to accept a High as "switch pressed".

Comment: So lets say I switched all my buttons to pulldowns on the pi, would this prevent floating/random input?

Comment: Yes - a pull-down resistor on an input will ensure that the input is Low, unless pulled up by a switch, just as a pull-up resistor on an input ensures that the input will be High unless pulled down by a switch.